# What is a parse tree object?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-internals

I have looked into `sys.syscachedobjects` table. I found some records have an object type of `parsetree`.

Can anyone tell me in detail what a `parsetree` is? Is this a data structure used by SQL Server, and can it help simplify my job as a DBA?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree

Comment: [Some info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9811331/73226)

Answer (score 1):

The breakdown of your code by by SQL server is checked by the engine for any issues.  If it does not find them it generates a parse tree and passes it to the algebrizer.  It is another way to represent the query.

Comment: So DBA does not need to worry about parsetree type objects. right?

Comment: It is an important concept for understanding query optimization.  You can take a look at the link Aaron posted above for some good information.  If you want more information regarding query performance and Execution Plan Cache Analysis I would recommend that you get a copy of [SQL Server 2008 Query Performance Tuning Distilled](http://amzn.to/JwEj0l).